# Haskell - Echoing all characters besides spaces

Tags: haskell

I am supposed to have an input of `[Char]` and output `[Char]` but from the input double all the characters twice besides the spaces.

I can double each character including the spaces but can not figure out how to exclude the spaces.

```
echo :: [Char] -> [Char]
echo x = concatMap (replicate 2) x
```

This will take `"Hello World"` and output `"HHeelloo  WWoorrlldd"` (2 spaces)

but I want it to output `"HHeelloo WWoorrlldd"` (1 space)

Any ideas would be helpful!

Edit: Thanks for all the helpful ideas! I have been able to figure out how to properly implement this!

Comment: Try to use an if-then-else -- or even better a recursive function with a guard?

Comment: @Lorenzo Thanks I'm new to Haskell, but in any other programming language this would be simple, but in Haskell I don't know how to iterate through the list only one character at time.

Comment: Can you write a function `Char -> [Char]` that turns any character `'x'` into a list `['x', 'x']`, but turns spaces into just `[' ']`?

Comment: In Haskell you don't (generally) iterate through something. Such tasks are often done with recursion instead - but more often with useful library functions. It can be quite a change of mindset, but in functional programming you don't think "what steps do I need to take to solve this", you think "what transformations do I need to do on the data (that is, which functions do I apply, and in what order)". In this case you're actually made a good start, I would suggest to look into the `words` function.

Comment: You _are_ iterating through the list via `concatMap`.  Just change `replciate 2` to "replicate 2 if it isn't a space, replicate 1 otherwise".

Comment: Hint: `words "Hello Word" == ["Hello", "World"]`. There is also `unwords`, which is close enough to an inverse of `words` for your purposes.

Comment: `words` will not help you solve this problem. Ignore comments that tell you to use it.

Comment: @melpomene I think that's too strong a statement. `words` and `unwords` is definitely the basis of *one* way to solve this - and the one I personally would most naturally think of. I see you are hinting towards another way to do it, and that's absolutely fine - it may be that your way feels natural to the OP. (Which on reflection it probably will, I admit.) I think this is a good way to show that there is usually more than one way to solve a problem, and I don't think it's helpful to claim that another solution is somehow invalid.

Comment: `words` could be a solution, but only if collapsing whitespace is acceptable. If spaces need to be preserved as-is, `words` won't do.

Comment: @MichaelLitchard Erm? There's a perfectly good MCVE here: the code for `echo` is minimal, complete, and there is an input-output example with both the actual output and the desired output that makes the example verifiable.

Comment: good point but I cannot recind vote. it needs to be edited, then I can remove the downvote.

Comment: @RobinZigmond According to the spec in OP's question, `" x "` needs to become `" xx "` (a four-character string). You cannot do that with `words`.

Comment: Oh I see, you are correct that if the first character is a space then this doesn't work. Thanks for catching this edge case :)

Comment: I removed downvote

Answer (score 3):

Well, so you've observed that `replicate 2` doesn't quite do what you want, because it duplicates spaces when you don't want it to. So let's write a new function that checks if it's a space before deciding what to do, hey? You can use pattern matching to check if your input `Char` is a space, like this:

```
notReplicate2 :: Char -> [Char]
notReplicate2 ' ' = {- exercise -}
notReplicate2 anythingElse = {- exercise -}
```

Or, if you want to handle things like newlines, tabs, vertical tabs, etc. similarly to a single space character, you could put some meat on this skeleton instead:

```
import Data.Char

notReplicate2 :: Char -> [Char]
notReplicate2 c | isSpace c = {- exercise -}
                | otherwise = {- exercise -}
```